# Partition table by composite keys Spring Batch

Tags: spring-batch

I have an issue with Spring Batch when try to load big data from join 3 big tables `A,B,C` in one database for reader, and then passing resultset to writer and write them into another database (2 databases in difference servers).
The relationship in them:

```
A inner join B on A.a = B.b

B inner join C on B.d = C.c
```

I want to partition table A and run them with multiple threads to increase performance.

But table A has only a composite key is `(a,i,j)` and doesn't have any field for marker, and they are not number.

So how can I partition A by composite key?
And my approach to implement is correctly?

```
Table A has 4m records.
Table B has 29m.
Table C has 3m.
```

Note: if I don't partition table, I get the error java heap space when run with whole data. So how Spring Batch works with big data?

Comment: - I'm using sybase database, relationship between table A and table C are n-n,  B contains foreign keys of A and B and another fields.

Comment: No body help me. But i have resolved my problem as well.